Flutter web app not working with AppCheck (enterprise reCaptcha)
I followed the steps described here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers
And I set up my token here:
https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha
although it says "Finish setting up your key: Request scores", it doesn't seem like this applies to my flutter web app. I also switched on Disable domain verification, just to make sure it's not blocking localhost (although I added localhost to the domains list).
In the app, I added the tag to index.html <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app-check.js"></script> and I'm initiating app check like so:
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  final appCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.instance;
  print("we're also here");
  appCheck.activate(
    webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider(appCheckToken),
  );

In the Firebase console, I registered the web app with appchceck

Once I started enforcing appcheck, the app doesn't connect anymore, and in the app check request metrics, it shows no verified requests and the new requests being made are shown as invalid: 
And the app is getting rejected with 400. Details from the network tab:
Request URL:https://content-firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1/projects/opincare-fbd30/apps/1:158357163473:web:33f42ed1a1c65248df2970:exchangeRecaptchaV3Token?key=AIzaSyCnQuY6rcVU4JTXH85GmBpYXNkd0K_cFpw
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:172.217.17.138:443
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin

In the debug console, it shows this:
[2024-06-01T13:04:40.535Z]  @firebase/app-check:
[2024-06-01T13:04:40.537Z]  @firebase/app-check:
Error
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 299:10              
createErrorWithStack
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 355:28            _throw
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 120:5                                           throwWithStackTrace
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1385:11                                          callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop  

Any help would be valued.

the actual values in the request URL line are modified here, since it seems like sensitive info

Same issue here.

@DarariNurAmali it seems nobody's touching this even with a bounty. Did you happen to figure anything out?

I am having here the same issue as well but for you just checking since the appcheck is lazyloading you need to await it and next making the main void a future like this
 Future<void> main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
 await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.web);
  try {
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
  webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider(
    kWebRecaptchaSiteKey,
   ),
 );

 } catch (e) {
   print("Error with app check $e");
 }}


I don't understand why they haven't fixed this issue yet but here we are.
TLDR: The solution is to inject the recaptcha site key and type into the applications session storage.

We're going to need to edit/create 3 files:

A dummy file

appcheck.dart
void writeFirebaseAppCheckInfoToSessionStorage() {
// This is the implementation for all the other platforms. Without this flutter compiles only for web
}



The file in which we make the web specific changes

web_appcheck.dart
// ignore: avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter
import 'dart:html'; // This won't compile if imported on a different platform than web
Map<String, dynamic> readFirebaseAppCheckInfoFromSessionStorage() {
  final recaptchaType = window.sessionStorage['FlutterFire-[DEFAULT]-recaptchaType'];
  final recaptchaSiteKey = window.sessionStorage['FlutterFire-[DEFAULT]-recaptchaSiteKey'];
  return {
    'recaptchaType': recaptchaType,
    'recaptchaSiteKey': recaptchaSiteKey,
  };
}

void writeFirebaseAppCheckInfoToSessionStorage() {
  try {
    final value = readFirebaseAppCheckInfoFromSessionStorage();
    if (value['recaptchaSiteKey'] == null && value['recaptchaType'] == null) {
      window.sessionStorage.addAll({
        'FlutterFire-[DEFAULT]-recaptchaType': 'enterprise', // replace with 'recaptcha-v3' if you're not using the enterprise recaptcha
        'FlutterFire-[DEFAULT]-recaptchaSiteKey': Tokens.reCaptchaEnterprise // replace with your own site recaptcha key,
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Error writing Firebase App Check info to session storage: $e');
    }
  }
}



executing it in main

main.dart
import 'appcheck.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'web_appcheck.dart';
import 'package:firebase_app_check/firebase_app_check.dart';
// other imports...


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (kIsWeb) {
    writeFirebaseAppCheckInfoToSessionStorage();
  }
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(// I agree with awaiting. Hovewer keep in mind it might slow your app a bit
      webProvider: ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider(Tokens.reCaptchaEnterprise),// replace with your own site recaptcha key, and type
    );
  //...other code
}

For some reason the flutter sdk doesn't do this soon enough and it sends invalid requests (Both to firebase auth if you have appcheck enabled for it and to appcheck itself). Here are the issues tracking it:
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11060 (closed)
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11828#issuecomment-1813970253 (open)
There is no need to import any firebase app check modules in index.html. You can remove those
Also make sure to double check that the site key you're putting into the code is from:
Recaptcha enterprise: https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha. 
Recaptcha v3: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
Other keys will not work.
Here you can see the number of invalid requests goes down drastically. This is when I made the switch from the alternative that I'm showing below:

28. December is the alternative approach while 29. December is the approach above
Alternative
In case the first code sample doesn't work for you I have another way I managed to get it to work.
Be warned
This alternative isn't perfect as I have experienced some issues when using app check along with firebase auth. The auth session wouldn't persist as the request to login with a persisted auth session was being made before the site key was injected. This resulted in deleting the users session auth
This is mainly to give you another direction in case the first one doesn't work for you
I've experimented a bit with importing firebase packages and came out with this solution
add these to
index.html

// This also works but not as good as the solution above
// The token gets injected a bit after initializing and can miss a few first requests (not include the app check header)
// Also the recaptcha icon shows up
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app-check.js"></script>
  <script>
    if (window.location.hostname != "localhost") {
      // Load the second script if not localhost
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=YOUR-RECAPTCHA-ENTERPRISE-SITE-KEY";
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
  </script>

